# Common queue for accessing shared resources in CGD

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have an array, `sharedArray`, of objects that are slow to create. I first create them and insert them in the array concurrently. After that, some readers concurrently access this `sharedArray`, get the objects in it and process it in their own way. I am experiencing crashes that I suppose come from not accessing the shared resource correctly. Am I doing it wrong?

I am using ARC, with iOS target deployment version 5.1. I get the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when setting the resources (marked in the code).

Thank you very much!

```
//Creation of the array
dispatch_queue_t constructionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("constructionQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_apply(numberOfSlowObjects, constructionQueue, ^(size_t i) {
    __block SlowObject *slowOb = [[SlowObject alloc] init];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [sharedArray setObject:slowOb atIndexedSubscript:i]; //HERE I GET THE ERROR
    });
});
dispatch_release(constructionQueue);

//Accessing the array from the different readers
dispatch_queue_t readersQueue = dispatch_queue_create("readersQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_apply(readers.count, readersQueue, ^(size_t i) {
    Reader *reader = [readers objectAtIndex:i];
    dispatch_queue_t processQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_apply(numberOfSlowObjects, processQueue, ^(size_t j) {
        __block SlowObject *slowOb;
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            slowOb = [sharedArray objectAtIndex:j];
        });
        [reader process:slowOb];
    });
    dispatch_release(processQueue);
});
dispatch_release(readersQueue);
```

And the code of `sharedArray` (the shared resource) lazy initialization:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) sharedArray
{
    if(!_sharedArray){
        _sharedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfSlowObjects];
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfSlowObjects;i++) [_sharedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; //null initialization;
    }
    return _sharedArray;
}
```

Comment: What message do you get when this crashes?

Comment: You get the above error on this line  slowOb = [sharedArray objectAtIndex:j];?

Please mark it in the code

Comment: Since you are running everything concurrently you need to put some NSLogs to ensure everything is behaving. For instance, a NSLog for numberOfSlowObjects to make sure it's assigned a value and for J. Then you need to see if there is anything in sharedArray by the time it is being accessed.

Comment: Are you using ARC? What version of the iOS SDK are you using? On what queue do you run this code?

Comment: I am using ARC, with deployment target 5.1. The queue is run in another queue (a camera queue from AVFoundation).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't have something initialized by the time you execute it, you have zero checks in place and run everything concurrently which means some code could be trying to access values that may not exist yet.

Since this would be difficult to trouble shoot with the small picture you are providing, I would suggested putting some NSLogs or debug and step through to see exactly what is going on when the execution gets to your array.

My guess "j" (numberOfSlowObjects) or "sharedArray" doesn't exist when you try an access it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. First, I do not know very well the best way to debug parallel execution: where would you suggest to put the NSLog? The error does not appear very often. Secondly, I also have updated where specifically in the code I get the error. As you see, is while setting the value in a specified position of an already existing array.

Comment: Great, lets start off with making sure sharedArray is set to NSMutableArray? Is this correct? Also, where are you initializing the sharedArray?

Comment: It is a NSMutableArray, declared as atomic. I initialize it in with the lazy initialization way. When I call it, if it is not set, I create it filling it with `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`.